# jQuery: Highlight sub menu when rollover main menu?

Tags: jquery

I have a nav & a secondary nav, both always on show.... but want I want to happen is, when you rollover "portfolio" in the main nav... I would like the "secondary nav" to light up e.g. apply a new class (with amore visible font colour)... how can this be done please?

(And when you roll off "portfolio" the font colours go back to normal in the secondary nav)

```
<ul id="primarynav">
    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
    <li class="portfolio"><a href="">protfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Secondary nav -->

<ul id="secondarynav">
    <li><a href="">Websites</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Graphics</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Drawing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is so strange what you want to achieve. Having an already visible sub-menu (that actually is your #secundarynav), but on hover the primary - enlighten the secondary. BTW: what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $primarynav = $('#primarynav'),
        $secondarynav = $('#secondarynav');

    $primarynav.hover(function(){
        $secondarynav.addClass('highlight');
    }, function(){
        $secondarynav.removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, tell `<li class="portfolio">` to execute a method once you hover the element:

```
<li class="portfolio" onmouseover="highlightSecundarynav();">..</li>
```

Then write the method `highlightSecundarynav()` which will add the class to the secundary nav:

```
function highlightSecundarynav() {
  document.getElementById("secondarynav").setAttribute("class", "highlight");
}
```

You can then add some CSS rules to apply the colours or other styles:

```
ul#secondarynav.highlight {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

You must do the same to remove the highlights once the mouse leaves the portfolio button:

```
<li class="portfolio" onmouseover="highlightSecundarynav();" onmouseout="unhighlightSecundarynav();">..</li>
```

Javascript:

```
function unhighlightSecundarynav() {
  document.getElementById("secondarynav").setAttribute("class", "");
}
```